# Power Point AddIn works even after Uninstall

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, add-in, office-addins

I Have developed an addin for Power Point where i have placed all my needed controls in ribbon

[image]

it works cool and everything was fine . But even after when i uninstall my addin the ribbon was visible in the power point till i restart my computer or need to go here and close 
[image]

after that when i reopen the power point again the ribbon control disappears. Why its so ?? why its not getting disappear at once when in un-installed the  addin .. But i have developed addin for Word and excel too its working properly.Only i face this issue in PowerPoint.

```
 private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.tab1 = this.Factory.CreateRibbonTab();
        this.group1 = this.Factory.CreateRibbonGroup();
        this.box1 = this.Factory.CreateRibbonBox();
        this.ModelNameTextBox = this.Factory.CreateRibbonEditBox();
        this.btnCHooseModelPath = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.btnProjectBrowser = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.btnRefresh = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.tab1.SuspendLayout();
        this.group1.SuspendLayout();
        this.box1.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // tab1
        // 
        this.tab1.ControlId.ControlIdType = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlIdType.Office;
        this.tab1.Groups.Add(this.group1);
        this.tab1.Label = "EA Plug In";
        this.tab1.Name = "tab1";
        // 
        // group1
        // 
        this.group1.Items.Add(this.box1);
        this.group1.Items.Add(this.btnProjectBrowser);
        this.group1.Items.Add(this.btnRefresh);
        this.group1.Label = "Settings";
        this.group1.Name = "group1";
        // 
        // box1
        // 
        this.box1.Items.Add(this.ModelNameTextBox);
        this.box1.Items.Add(this.btnCHooseModelPath);
        this.box1.Name = "box1";
        // 
        // ModelNameTextBox
        // 
        this.ModelNameTextBox.Label = "Select Model      ";
        this.ModelNameTextBox.Name = "ModelNameTextBox";
        this.ModelNameTextBox.SizeString = "qqqqqqqqqqxxxxxxxxxxqqqqqqqqqq";
        this.ModelNameTextBox.Text = null;
        // 
        // btnCHooseModelPath
        // 
        this.btnCHooseModelPath.Image = global::EAWIPpt.Properties.Resources.Browse;
        this.btnCHooseModelPath.Label = "button1";
        this.btnCHooseModelPath.Name = "btnCHooseModelPath";
        this.btnCHooseModelPath.ScreenTip = "Open EAP model";
        this.btnCHooseModelPath.ShowImage = true;
        this.btnCHooseModelPath.ShowLabel = false;
        this.btnCHooseModelPath.SuperTip = "Used to open EAP model";
        this.btnCHooseModelPath.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.btnCHooseModelPath_Click);
        // 
        // btnProjectBrowser
        // 
        this.btnProjectBrowser.Label = "ProjectBrowser";
        this.btnProjectBrowser.Name = "btnProjectBrowser";
        this.btnProjectBrowser.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.btnProjectBrowser_Click);
        // 
        // btnRefresh
        // 
        this.btnRefresh.Label = "Refresh";
        this.btnRefresh.Name = "btnRefresh";
        this.btnRefresh.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.btnRefresh_Click);
        // 
        // PptRibbon
        // 
        this.Name = "PptRibbon";
        this.RibbonType = "Microsoft.PowerPoint.Presentation";
        this.Tabs.Add(this.tab1);
        this.Load += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonUIEventHandler(this.PptRibbon_Load);
        this.tab1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tab1.PerformLayout();
        this.group1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.group1.PerformLayout();
        this.box1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.box1.PerformLayout();

    }
```

the above is the code in my InitializeComponent of ribbon designer

Comment: can you post your InitializeComponent() method's code of the ribbon designer.cs class?

Comment: You don't mention whether this is a COM, VBA or some other type of add-in.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Its a COM Add-In

Comment: This might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23888170/ribbon-tab-exists-even-after-uninstalling-powerpoint-add-in/24772782#24772782